# Forms in ModalPopupExtender in ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working on an ASP.net c# project. I have an aspx page where I have a form taking user input and a datagrid. When the user clicks on a link inside the datagrid it displays a modal popup extender with dynamic data. This is working fine.

What I want to be able to do is when the modal popup extender is opened it has a form that can also take user input. However, I am having a problem that when I try to enter data into the form in the modal popup extender and i press the submit button it is first checking the form on the proper page, not in the modal popup extender, which is preventing the form on the modal popup extender from being submitted.

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it's firing validators on the form on the main page and not allowing you to submit the modal form?

If that's the case you can change the form on your main page to [use a different ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) so it doesn't fire when you submit the modal form.